# Supermicro Caddies - mounting 2.5" SATA disks in 3.5" caddies

Tags: sata, supermicro

I need to replace some 3.5" drives with 2.5" SATA SSD's in an older (remote) Supermicro system where I do not know the Chassis model.

What I do know is the motherboard is an X10DRi motherboard (which dates the system around 2014/2015).

What I don't know - and hoping people can guide me on - is

- How many types of 3.5" caddies do Supermicro have (I mean physically, I could not care less if the front has a different design, as long as it slides into place and works?) - and if there are multiple caddy's - what do I need to look for for servers of that age?
- How do people typically mount 2.5" drives in Supermicro caddies?   A post I saw on Superuser hinted that drives are/can be bottom mounted - but was a bit vague/confusing as to whether a special insert is needed in the caddy?

Comment: `How many types of 3.5" Chassis do Supermicro have` that depends on the chassis.

Comment: Doh, I meant to ask how many caddies!

Comment: I figured so much. Nevertheless, the amount of disk slots depends on the chassis.